# Theorem 9.8 of Atiyah : why does it suffice to show for integral ideal in Ap?

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, dedekind-domain

I'm trying to prove => part of atiyah 9.8.
I understood everything but [image]

Can somebody help me to understand why does it suffice to show for integral ideal of Ap?

Comment: invertibility is a local property

Comment: I know. What we have to show here is every non-zero fractional ideal of Ap is invertible, and apply prop9.7. But my question is why it is enough to consider integral ideal of Ap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why it suffices to show integral ideal (instead of fractional ideal).

Suppose every integral ideal is invertible - (1).

Let M be a nonzero fractional ideal of A.
Then there is nonzero x in A s.t. xM is in A.
Now since xM is integral ideal, there is a A-submodule N of Frac(A) s.t. (xM)N=A by (1). Note that xN is a A-submodule N of Frac(A) and M(xN)=(xM)N=A.

So we can show that every fractional ideal is invertible.